# how to pass arguments up via props in functions with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In a class, I would write: this.prop.bind(this,arg)

like this:

```js
<button onClick={this.props.delete.bind(this, id)} id='deletebtn'>
                        X
                    </button>
```

but how would I do the same thing in a function?
I need to use a class or there is a way to do it without it?

ps: did hooks killed classes? if not when are classes really necessary?

Comment: The only purpose of binding `this` is so that in the method you can call another attribute or method of the same class. If you are not is a class, why would you have `this` in the first place? It is not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: in this case, `bind` is used to attach the argument `id` to the `delete` prop of the parent class, because I cant call `props.delete(id) because in that case it would call the function instead of passing it, that's why I use bind(this, id).

that way I can pass a parameter UP to the parent class.

Comment: I want the same thing as this, but using functions instead of classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a function that returns a function, like this:

```
function deleteItem(id) {
  return function() {
    ... <using `id`>
  }
}
```

or with arrow functions:

```
const deleteItem = (id) => {
  return () => {
    ... <using `id`>
  }
}
```

or even shorter:

```
const deleteItem = (id) => () => {
  ... <using `id`>
}
```

and then you do

```
<button onClick={deleteItem(id)} id='deletebtn'>
```

where `deleteItem(id)` is now a function.

To answer your question about hooks, they did not "kill classes" but provide a arguably better alternative only for React components. Class components are still supported. It is hard to imagine a situation that cannot be handled by the new functional components with hooks, though.

Comment: `delete` is a keyword in JS and cannot be used as a variable/function name

Comment: Right, replaced with `deleteItem`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a way,
Like @JulienD Said it, I just need it to create a function that returns a function
this is how I did it.

the child sends the argument to the parent

```js
<button onClick={() => {props.delPost(id)}}>delete</button>
```

the parent sends the argument up one more level

```js
 <Post delPost={(id)=>{props.delPost(id)}} key={post.id} postItem={post} />)
```

finally the root parent make use of the argument

```js
const deletePost = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
    }
<Feed delPost={deletePost} posts={posts} />
```

Comment: A tip for later: when you get tired of passing callbacks up and down the hierarchy until it is no more manageable, have a look at Redux.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `removeItem` handler down to the child component -

```js
const { useState } = React

const initialItems =
  [ "muffins", "cake", "pies" ]

const MyApp = ({ init = initialItems }) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(init)
  
  const removeItem = (pos = 0) => event =>
    setItems([...items.slice(0, pos), ...items.slice(pos + 1)])
  
  const addItem = event =>
    event.key === "Enter"
      ? setItems([...items, event.target.value ])
      : null
    
  return <div>
    {items.map((name, i) =>
      <Item name={name} onDelete={removeItem(i)} />
    )}
    <div className="item">
      <input onKeyDown={addItem} placeholder="Type here and press [ENTER]..." />
    </div>
  </div>
}

const Item = ({ name = "", onDelete }) =>
  <div className="item">
    {name} &nbsp;
    <button onClick={onDelete}>️</button>
  </div>
  
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.body)
```

```css
body {
 font-family: monospace;
}

.item {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

input {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```